# How to validate that a string is a valid date in Python

Tags: python, django

I have a model in Django that has two **DateField**s, but sometimes they receive wrong dates from the front-end, like '20196-10-23'. Even when it might actually be a valid date (crazy, but legit), python doesn't allow to compare both dates due to this error: `TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'datetime.date' and 'str'`, so I want to use `clean()` method to verify that both dates are valid ones, but I always get dates wrong, even when they are correct.

This is the code for `clean()` method:

```
def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            Reservation.objects.get(booking=self.booking)
        except:
            pass
        else:
            raise CustomValidation(_('Booking already exists.'), 'booking', status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        print("{}/{}".format(self.arrival_date, self.departure_date))

        try:
            datetime.strptime(self.arrival_date, "%Y-%m-%d")
        except:
            raise CustomValidation(_('Arrival date must be a valid date.'), 'arrival_date', status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        if self.arrival_date >= self.departure_date:
            raise CustomValidation(_('Departure date must be later than Arrival date.'), 'departure_date', status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        elif self.arrival_date <= timezone.datetime.now().date():
            if self.id == None:
                raise CustomValidation(_('Arrival date must be later than today.'), 'arrival_date', status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        if self.status == 'CONFIRMED' and self.confirmation is None:
            raise CustomValidation(_('Must provide a confirmation number.'), 'confirmation', status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I always get an exception, even when the date is correct.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642892/calculating-if-date-is-in-start-future-or-present-in-python Might be useful

Comment: The error is presumably happening on the line `if self.arrival_date >= self.departure_date:`, so it's telling you that `departure_date` is a string, not arrival_date. How is this data getting entered? It would probably be better to use a form.

Comment: It always get entered the same way, but when the date is a crazy one ('20196-11-17', in this case), python treats it as a string.

Comment: Should departure_date also be validated for a valid date format like arrival_date is?

Comment: Yes, it should, but I haven't added that yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While 20196 is conceptually a valid year, Python won't allow it. I tried this...

```
import datetime
from datetime import date

def clean(arrival_date):
    return date(*map(int, arrival_date.split("-")))

print(clean("20196-10-23"))
# ValueError: year is out of range
```

...and found out there's actually a hard-coded [maximum year value of 9999](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html#datetime.MAXYEAR) for Python dates.

So while you could technically validate the format in various ways, you won't be able to handle dates like this with the built-in `datetime` module.

Answer (score 0):

I usually first set both dates as `datetime.strptime()`:

```
try:
    #get the dates 
    my_date_time_1 = self.cleaned_data['date_1']
    my_date_time_2 = self.cleaned_data['date_2']
    #set the datetime
    my_date_time_1 = datetime.strptime(my_date_time_1, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    my_date_time_2 = datetime.strptime(my_date_time_2, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
except:
    raise forms.ValidationError(u'Wrong Date Format')    


#and then compare dates
if my_date_time_1 >= my_date_time_2:
        raise forms.ValidationError(u'Please check the dates')
```