# Django testing validate if model with future date not created

Tags: python, django-models, django-tests

I am writing a Django web app and I'm having a problem with writing test method for my model and I hope you will be able to help me with it.

I created a model:

```
class Animal(models.Model):
    date_born = models.DateTimeField('date_born', validators=[MaxValueValidator(limit_value=timezone.now())])
```

New Animal instance should not be created if date_born is set to future date.
I am trying to write a test in tests.py to validate if model with future date is not being created but I am not sure how to do it.
Could you advise me?

Comment: This should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642892/calculating-if-date-is-in-start-future-or-present-in-python/3642942

Answer (score 0):

from what i am guessing from your question, the problem is that you want to make sure the value of `date_born` is always the current time, if so then in that case there is a `auto_now_add` keyword argument in django datetime model and it recieves a boolean. It's default to `False` and can be set to `True` and django will take care of the rest.